# Unity and UnityContainer

Tags: c#, wcf, unity-container

I have many projects :

- Service.DataAccess
- Service.DataAccess.Interfaces
- Service.Main
- Service.Factory

`Service.DataAccess` have a reference to `Service.DataAccess.Interfaces`.

`Service.Main` have a reference to `Service.DataAccess.Interfaces` and to `Service.Factory`

In `Service.Main` I have :

```
var instance = Service.Factory.ObjectFactory.Resolve<Service.DataAccess.Interfaces.IDataAccessLayer>();
```

In `Service.Factory` :

```
public void InitContainer(IUnityContainer container)
{
    var section = (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity");

    section.Configure(container); //Exception here!
}
```

In my configuration file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <container>
        <register type="Service.DataAccess.Interfaces.IDataAccessLayer, Service.DataAccess.Interfaces"
                  mapTo="Service.DataAccess.DataAccessLayer, Service.DataAccess" />
    </container>
</unity>
```

But I have a exception at runtime in `InitContainer` method :

```
The type name or alias Service.DataAccess.Interfaces.IDataAccessLayer could not be resolved. Please check your configuration file and verify this type name.
```

I don't understand

Thank's!

Comment: Does the Service.Factory-project have a reference to Service.DataAccess? Unity needs to be able to access a constructor for the implementation.

Comment: Service.Factory don't have a reference to Service.DataAccess or Service.DataAccess.Interfaces . He must have a reference to which project ? Both ? Or only the project with 'physical' class ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your container need to be able to access the constructor of your implementation. So it needs access to a public constructor of the class `Service.DataAccess.DataAccessLayer`, which means that your `Service.Factory`  needs to reference `Service.DataAccess`. But also `Service.DataAccess.Interfaces`, because otherwise it will not find the interface.

You may also separate it into several steps, and let each library take care of their own registrations.

`Main` doesn't necessarily need have a reference to `Service.DataAccess` if it goes through `Service.Factory` to create it. Let's take a very simple example.

In your **Main**:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.Register<IFactory, SomeFactory>(); // Factory is a class in Service.Factory.

// Let your factory project take care of it's registrations as well.
Service.Factory.Startup.InitContainer(container);

var factory = container.Resolve<IFactory>();
Service.DataAccess.Interfaces.IDataInterface foo = factory.Create();
```

In your **Service.Factory**:

```
// Class for initiating registrations.
public static class Startup
{
    public static InitContainer(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        var section = (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity");
        section.Configure(container);
    }
}

// Some example class...
public class SomeFactory : IFactory
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;

    public SomeFactory(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public IDataInterface Create()
    {
        // return the implementation.
        return _container.Resolve<IDataInterface>();
    }
}
```

Note that the `SomeFactory` uses the [ServiceLocator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/). But it's mostly a proof-of-concept to show how it *could* work. It's a way to let `Service.Main` only reference the interfaces, but not the concrete classes. `Service.Factory`, however, needs to reference both.

Comment: Thank for this quick and complete response

Comment: If you wait two minutes you will get longer and more complete answer.

Comment: Thank's! So my factory project have a reference to all others projects and my main project have a reference to only `interface` projects ?

Comment: Your Factory-project may not need a reference to Main, but it needs references to the others.

Comment: Yes all projects without Main project. Thank's a lot !!